# How to Debug.print into a column or text field in Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is there a way to print out results from `Debug.print` into a cell on a form instead of just printing in Immediate window? ps. I borrowed this code to generate passwords.

```vb
Private Sub Command23_Click()
Dim s As String * 8 'fixed length string with 8 characters
Dim n As Integer
Dim ch As Integer 'the character
For n = 1 To Len(s) 'don't hardcode the length twice
    Do
        ch = Rnd() * 127 'This could be more efficient.
        '48 is '0', 57 is '9', 65 is 'A', 90 is 'Z', 97 is 'a', 122 is 'z'.
    Loop While ch < 48 Or ch > 57 And ch < 65 Or ch > 90 And ch < 97 Or ch > 122
    Mid(s, n, 1) = Chr(ch) 'bit more efficient than concatenation
Next

Debug.Print s
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a text box to the form, and assign `s` as the text box's `Value` ...

```vb
Debug.Print s
Me!txtDebug.Value = s
```

If you want to append `s` to the text box `Value` (instead of replacing `Value` each time), you could add the new `s` value as a new line ...

```vb
Me!txtDebug.Value = Me!txtDebug.Value & vbCrLf & s
```

Comment: how about printing into a table's cell?

Comment: Never mind I figured it out. Thank you for your help.